# Error Assembly DLL

Tags: c#, iis, dll, .net-assembly

Im new in this, i want to deploy a web service in ISS 7.5, all is well but when i try to consume the WS, i get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'rsaws, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=90e904cb4316068a' 
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

I have the dll rsaws in the path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\bin" and the version is the 8.1.0.0, i changed my file web.config as follow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings configSource="Parametros.config" />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <clear />
                <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="mscorlib" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <add assembly="*" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
  </system.web>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="rsaws.dll" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.1.0.0" newVersion="8.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceNetSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceNetSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>    

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:433/ServiceNet.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceNetSoap" contract="WebServiceNetSoap" name="WebServiceNetSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:433/ServiceNet.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceNetSoap12" contract="WebServiceNetSoap" name="WebServiceNetSoap12" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceNet.ServiceNetBehavior">         
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" findValue="ARA-GGRAL" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceNet.ServiceNet" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceNet.ServiceNetBehavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceNet.IServiceNet">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.

          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="ServiceNet.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Notes: -If I add assembly gives me the error that "can not load file"
       -I don't see dll in GAC

Any solutions?????  Thanks

Comment: What .net version is your application pool using?

Comment: if you do not GAC  the dll that you have created .. how come you can't just set the copy local property of that dll to true.. or can you not place that .dll assembly in a common folder and remove the original reference and re-add it to the project from the shared / common location..?

Comment: .NET v4.0. by the way it is an example in other words i didn't develop, so i don't know where is the original reference (not on web.config) but if add new reference can not load the file